# How to easily host a WAN server purely for testing

Tags: networking, lua, udp, love2d, luasocket

I'm working on a 2D top-down multiplayer game, and though I have thoroughly tested it on my LAN network, I would like to distribute it to some friends accross the world so they can test it too. I have read a few topics on hosting WAN servers but it's always for professional things or for websites, but I just want a simple server on which only few people will connect.

I started learning networking just a week ago, so I only know the basics, and if there's a way for them to connect directly to my computer somehow, I'd be happy to know.

I'm using Lua, Love2D and LuaSocket(UDP)

Comment: Find your public IP with whatismyip.com ... you might want to map it to a name with no-ip.com ... you'll need to open a port in your firewall. Read about NAT rules.

Answer (score 0):

Networking is all about IP addresses. If you are trying to play with both IPv4 and IPv6, get your own IP address via http://whatismyip.live or whatismyip.host etc and (like sorak said) map it with free tools like noip.com . Websites will only give you external IP address. If you are looking for creating a LAN without internet then you would need to find IP address from the network settings.